# Assign objects to array

Tags: java

Not really sure how to assign objects to the array, help me please

Which class do i do it in?

```
package Assignment2;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Agent {

   private int NumberOfHouses;

   public static void main(String[] args){
   House test = new House();
   House[] allHouses = new House[10];   
   test.setNumberOfRooms(12);
   System.out.println(test.getNumberOfRooms());
   allHouses[2].setNumberOfRooms(9);
   }
```

}

```
package Assignment2;

public class House {

   private int NumberOfRooms = 0, LivingArea, TotalLotArea;
   private Boolean Status; 
   private long Price; 
   static int test;

   public void setNumberOfRooms(int num){
       NumberOfRooms = num;
   }
   public void setLivingArea(int num){
       LivingArea = num;
   }
   public void setTotalLotArea(int num){
       TotalLotArea = num;
   }
       public void setPrice(long num){
       Price = num;
   }
   public int getNumberOfRooms(){
       return NumberOfRooms;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign Objects to an Array as follows

```
    House[] allHouses = new House[10];
    for(int i=0;i<allHouses.length;i++) {
        allHouses[i] = new House();
        allHouses[i].setNumberOfRooms(someIntValue);
    }
```

Comment: hmm i like this, i think im getting somewhere

Answer (score 1):

When you do the line `House[] allHouses = new House[10];`, you are not creating 10 House objects, instead just mentioning that the array `allHouses` can store references for up to 10 `House` objects.

So after that you would have to create a new object for each position, set the values and assign it to a location in the array.

Initially, the array would be empty (won't refer to any objects), and you have to put objects into it.

The reason I explained like this and instead of writing just the code, is that you should understand what is going on and not depend on SO for ready baked code :)

Comment: _you are not creating 10 House objects_ Yes he is. They are all just `null`.

Comment: @DaftPunk, I think you are contradicting yourself. How is it possible to create 10 House objects and at the same time their value be `null`.

Comment: @DaftPunk `null` is not an object.

Comment: @DaftPunk and silverback are both wrong.  It is not 10 House objects, and the array is NOT capable of storing 10 Houses.  It is an array that can store 10 ***reference*** of House. Of course, that's not 10 House object, you can say there are 10 null ***reference*** of House.

Comment: @DaftPunk Non sequiturs? What? Where do you see a non sequitur?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign objects to an array like this:

```
allHouses[2] = new House();
allHouses[2].setNumberOfRooms(9);
```

Comment: How do you define allHouses in this case?